# AngularJs ngRoute and Umbraco Custom Section URL. what wrong with the code

Tags: angularjs, umbraco7, ngroute, custom-server-controls

I have a customsection in Umbraco 7.7.x called homeSection defined in dashboard.config file for the dashboard. however trying to load another view within the main view which doesnt work.
Please help!

Index.html code

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="?#/homeSection/#main"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
<li><a href="?#/homeSection/#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
<li><a href="?#/homeSection/#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and app.js code:

```html
 $routeProvider
        .when('#/homeSection/main', {
            templateUrl: "'<control addPanel='true' panelCaption=''>/app_plugins/TheDashboard/backoffice/Organisation/HomeDashboard/main.html'",
            controller: "MainController"
        })
```

but no main page loading. Please advise and help!!

thanks

Comment: templateURL expect a URL not a tag remove this <control addPanel='true' panelCaption=''>

Answer (score 0):

Hi Arther are you following a guide to create your custom section?

A good example of one I used to get started was:
http://www.enkelmedia.se/blogg/2013/11/22/creating-custom-sections-in-umbraco-7-part-1.aspx